# android - The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call AccountKit.initialize() first

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit

I got this error when using Facebook Account Kit. When I debug my program the method `Accountkit.GetCurrentAccessToken()!=null` causes this error.
When I remove this. Then somewhere but not in the code I write causes this error also. I have tried editing the manifest.xml but I had no luck. 
Can anyone help me fix this ?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.featuring.beta.featuringbeta, PID: 26749
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.featuring.beta.featuringbeta/com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity}: 500: Initialization error: 501: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call AccountKit.initialize() first
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2330)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5261)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:734)
               Caused by: 500: Initialization error: 501: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call AccountKit.initialize() first
                  at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:53)
                  at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Initializer.getLoginManager(Initializer.java:199)
```

Thanks.

Note I made a new project with Accountkit it works fine. When I put the code in my project for the signup and login, it causes this error.

Comment: did you write `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);` ???

Comment: @Codus no, i did not. i tried to use it but  it cannot be resolve. note that i am using Account kit not facebook Login. thanks for the response

Comment: but the trace says that you need to call `AccountKit.initialize()` first (sorry for i typed wrong word.

Comment: @Codus if u mean AccountKit.Initialize() yes i write it in my code but still got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you initialize the account kit in application class like this

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AccountKit.initialize(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

After that in Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.you.yourapp">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment: all the facebook developer console side setting is properly done?

Comment: again make sure your app id , client id and app protocol schema id is correct?

Comment: i am pretty sure the app id and client id is correct but don't know about the schema id. but the thing is when i make new project it seems to work just fine. but when i put it into my app and that error happened.  i know the problem in my app but just didn't know where is it.